# How Can I Make a JTextField's Width Static?

Tags: java, swing, text, resize, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField` in my `JFrame` and I set the text in the `JTextField`.

When the text is long, `JTextField` gets the text's length and then jTextField's new width is equal to the text. It changes my window's shape and  other components' places. How can I make `JTextField`s have static width so they won't be resized based on the length of the text that pass in?

Comment: Which layout are you using in the text field's parent container? Do you specify any min/max/preferred sizes for the text field?

Comment: i don't use any layout. the layout is seem as "free design", i did not changed min max preferred sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing you can do is set the column width, usually during initialization of the JTextField, e.g.:

```
new JTextField("Hello World!", 5);
new JTextField(10);
```

But the container will have a layout manager -- if you didn't specify it explicitly, it likely has a default. `JFrame` starts with `BorderLayout` in the content pane, although if you've added any other panels between the `JFrame` and the `JTextField`, we'd need to know that to have a better sense of the layout manager.

Some layout managers will constrain the width of the field as well, which is another way you might address your problem.